# What is the purpose of the TBitmap.BitmapScale property?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi, what is the purpose of FireMonkey's `TBitmap.BitmapScale` property? Embarcadero's documentation says nothing about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It controls the scale in which the bitmap is rendered, such as in a `TImageViewer`.  A value of 1 is 100%.  You can set the scale to a lesser value to zoom out, and to a higher value to zoom in.